# Can a materialized view in Netezza be created by the union of 2 base tables

Tags: ddl, create-table, netezza, union-all, materialized

I have 2 or more base tables representing subtype entities. The records in these are mutually exclusive - no intersection. I want to create a materialized view which represents the supertype entity. Can this be done in Netezza using a UNION ALL in the create of the view?

Answer (score 0):

> Can this be done in Netezza using a UNION ALL in the create of the view?

Yes (via a "CREATE VIEW")

> I want to create a materialized view

In Netezza, a "CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW" is for a single table.